# Access and copy files from Windows server with openssh to my Ubuntu machine

Tags: ssh, windows, openssh

For development I use a Ubuntu machine.

I need to retrieve a file which is located on a Windows machine.

There is openssh installed on the Windows server.

I can log into the Windows server and then I get a prompt like this:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.1697]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

xxx\admin@WINDOWSSERVER C:\Users\admin>
```

The files are on the `E:` drive.

e.g. `E:\data\files`.

For file transfer between Linux and Linux I just use a command like...

```
scp box1.server.net:/srv/data/xxx.msg .
```

But what command do I have to use to get a file from a Windows machine, especially as the file is from a different (local) drive?

P.S.: There is no direct connection to the windows server - I am using a proxy configuration in my SSH config.

Comment: You probably need to look that up on a Winodws related help and support site, or consult Windows documentation. The fact that the recipient is an Ubuntu PC seems irrelevant.

Comment: Can't you do the scp transfer the other way, ie. run `scp` on Windows towards Ubuntu as a server?

Comment: @mikewhatever Well, I use Ubuntu and scp/ssh or maybe I could even use smbclient, so I def. think this question is valid here.

Comment: @raj Thanks, I already though about this, but then, I have no private key on the Windows server for the reverse login. But... afair there is a way to use ssh-add to transport one's own key along, and then scp from the remote server to another server. I will check that out. Thanks!